# Desktop notification in Gmail Web UI for messages added using "insert"

Tags: gmail-api

I'm writing an application that adds email messages to a Gmail inbox using the "insert" API call. I need the added messages to trigger a "new email" notification in the email clients connected to this inbox. This works with all the email clients I've tried, except with the Gmail Web UI. Not only Gmail doesn't trigger a desktop notification, but the new emails take up to 2 minutes to appear in the inbox.

I've tried using "import" instead of "insert" to add new emails, and that seems to get Gmail to trigger desktop notifications, unfortunately I can't really use "import" because I need to skip filters, among other reasons.

Is this a known issue of the Gmail Web UI? Does anyone know of a workaround to force Gmail to trigger a desktop notification?

Comment: Does it take 2 minutes to appear even if you click Refresh, or is it that it doesn't automatically appear for up to 2 minutes?

Comment: If I click Refresh then the message does appear immediately. What takes 2 minutes is for it to appear automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use import but then just undo the work done by the filters? I.e. move it back to the inbox, remove any labels from it, unstar it, etc.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Unfortunately, not all filters can be undone, e.g. forwarding.